# How to get Canonical id from gcm while registering a device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app with a server. I am saving the registration id of the device on the server.
If an app is re-installed on a device, the server gets two registration id's for one device and device receives two notification.

Answer (score 1):

Use device **IMEI** number if your app have not sign up or login facility for uniquely identify the device. may this will help you.
you can insert **IMEI** number or registration id of  newly registered mobile device into the server or if device is already registered then you can replace newly generated registration id by GCM.

**Code for Getting IMEI number of  Device**

```
String imei = ((TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService("phone")).getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Great solution! That's the only way I know if users have multiple devices.

Comment: What happens with tablets? do they have an IMEI?